# How to inherit dart documentation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one class that is documented, and another one is implementing that interface. How can I inherit the documentation as well?

```dart
class A {

   ///Documentation
   void documented(){}
}

class B implements A {
  var a = A();

  ///@inherit from A
  void documented(){}


}

// later I have instance of B and I would like to have documentation on method.

B().documented(); // documentation is empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try template:

```dart
class A {
  /// {@template fooTemplate}
  ///
  /// Your documentation goes here...
  ///
  /// {@endtemplate}
  void documented(){}
}

class B implements A {
  var a = A();

  /// {@macro fooTemplate}
  void documented(){}
}

void f() {
  B().documented(); // Valid documentation. 
}
```

Comment: *Warning*: This is potentially dangerous, as the `@template` is *not* scoped to the comment it is declared over and can be referenced by `@macro` anywhere.  According the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc#macros), `Template definitions are currently unscoped -- if dartdoc reads a file containing a template, it can be used in anything dartdoc is currently documenting. This can lead to inconsistent behavior between runs on different packages, especially if different command lines are used for dartdoc.`

Answer (score 3):

If your derived class doesn't need to add any additional documentation, you can just omit documentation for the overridden members in the derived class. `dartdoc` will automatically copy the documentation from the base class when generating documentation.