# How inheritDoc in dart?

Tags: dart

I'm just looking for a way to add some doc (dart ///) to derived methods (above inherited doc for example) in dart.

A lot of google search, but not found ...

Ideally, I would like an automatic inherited doc (as dart does in vscode), above the "local" doc. Or any other way to concatenate comments.

Comment: Does [How to inherit dart documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68362371/) help?

Comment: Thanks for the link, read it. I think that there is no solution.